# Define pool to use in a subsequent job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I would like to define in Job1 the pool that should be used in the Job2.

Here's the code I wrote that obviously doesn't work properly:

```
jobs:
- job: Job1
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - task: Bash@3
    name: DefineFlow
    displayName: Check if tag is correct and prepare pipeline
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        if [[ something happen ]]; then
          flow_type=0
        else 
          flow_type=1
        fi
        echo "flow type $flow_type"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=flow_type;isOutput=true]$flow_type"

- job: Job2
  dependsOn: Job1
  variables: 
    flow_type: $[ dependencies.Job1.outputs['DefineFlow.flow_type'] ]
  pool: 
    ${{ if eq(variables['flow_type'], '1') }}:
      name: selfhostedpool
    ${{ if eq(variables['flow_type'], '0') }}:
      vmimage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
...
```

What sounds strange is that if the flow_type variable is evaluated as 0 it would use correctly the windows-latest image. While if it is evaluated as 1 it would use the ubuntu-latest image (probably because it is the default image).

Comment: You can't. The pool needs to be able to be resolved at template compilation time, not at runtime. You can have two separate jobs, one for each pool, then dynamically enable them at runtime with a `condition`, though.

Comment: And that was also my initial thought. I wanted anyway to give it a try and I ended up having more doubts than before, can you help me understand why in the case the variable is evaluated as 0 it correctly uses `windows-latest` as image instead of `ubuntu-latest`?